# How to write a code to change color space of all image textures attached to Base Color of Principled BSDF of all materials?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to write a code to change color space of **all image textures** attached to **Base Color** of Principled BSDF of all materials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
```python
import bpy

                
def change_base_color_space(object, color_space='sRGB'):
    '''
    Change the color space of the base color image texture node.
    
    object (bpy.types.Object) - The object to take material from.
    color_space (enum in [‘Filmic Log’, ‘Filmic sRGB’, ‘Linear’, ‘Linear ACES’, ‘Linear ACEScg’, ‘Non-Color’, ‘Raw’, ‘sRGB’, ‘XYZ’], default ‘sRGB’) - Color space in the image file, to convert to and from when saving and loading the image.
    '''
    if object.material_slots:
        for slot in object.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                node_tree = slot.material.node_tree

                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED' and node.inputs['Base Color'].is_linked:
                        image_node =  node.inputs['Base Color'].links[0].from_node
                        if image_node.image:
                            image_node.image.colorspace_settings.name = color_space                            
                       
                
change_base_color_space(bpy.context.object, 'Non-Color')
````